# AnacondaにPyTorchをインストールしたのに、実際に使おうとするとエラーが出てしまいます

Tags: python, python3, macos, anaconda, pytorch

私はmacを使用しています。Anacondaは前から使っていたんですが、そこにPyTorchを入れようと思い次の方法でインストールを試みました。

まず、以下のサイトの「コマンドライン環境の設定」というところに書いてある手順を踏みました。

https://www.python.jp/install/anaconda/macos/install.html

次に、以下のサイト（pytorch公式サイト）のAnacondaへのインストール専用のコマンドをターミナルに入力して、インストールが完了しました（インストール完了直後に、このまま続けますか？みたいな質問が出てきたので(y)と回答しました）

URL→ https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
入力したコマンド→ `conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch`

しかし、その後AnacondaのJupyter Notebookで `[import torch]` と入力したら "[torch]は存在しません" というエラーが発生してしまいました。

どうすれば正常にPyTorchを使えるようになりますか？

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-eb42ca6e4af3> in <module>
----> 1 import torch

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

補足：
よく調べてみたところ、同じパッケージをcondaとpipで併用しているとエラーが起きるらしいのですが、私の場合、PyTorchはcondaにしか入れていません。他のは色々あってpipとconda両方に入れてたりしてたんですがPyTorchに関してはcondaだけです。

Comment: PyTorchをインストールしたのはanacondaのbase環境ですか？　エラーメッセージは実際のメッセージそのままを掲載してください。

Comment: 「ModuleNotFoundError」ということはPyTorchをインストールしたPython環境と、質問者さんがプログラムを実行したPython環境が異なっていると思われます。プログラムはどうやって実行しましたか？

Comment: [conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch]このコードはターミナルで入力して、実行はanaconda公式サイトからインストールしたのを使っていたのでそちらでしました

Comment: ”プログラム（import torch）の実行方法”について訊いています。jupyter notebookとかターミナルとかそういう意味です。

Comment: jupyter notebookで実行しました

Comment: 以前の質問> PyTorchをインストールしたのはanacondaのbase環境ですか？　についてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: いえ、直接ターミナルでcondaにpytorchをインストールして（上記の通りのコードで）、そのままanaconda jupyternotebookに[import torch]と入力しました（そしたらエラーが出ました）

Comment: ターミナルで conda list と入力すると、PyTorchは表示されますか？